# CakePHP & Change user's profile

Tags: cakephp

I have started learning cakePHP and now I am facing the following problem. How can allow my users to change their profile (their info in the DB).

This is my model -> http://bin.cakephp.org/view/798927304 I use these validations when someone tries to register .
This is my method for editing profiles: http://bin.cakephp.org/view/841227800

First I check does the user have the permission to edit this profile (is the profile his own).
Then get the desired id and try to save the request->data... But unfortunately without success.

And last this is my view -> http://bin.cakephp.org/view/1798312426

The only things I want to make are:
-Change their email (if they add new email)
-Change their social profiles (if the add them)
-Change their password (if they add it)

Can you guide me to do these things?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when you call a save, as in:

```
$this->User->save($this->request->data)
```

The data in $this->request->data is cleared by default.  In your edit method, you have an if statement below that is using the same save again.

The default functionality which I assume you have copied from a cakebaked edit method typically does the save and uses the returned logic to power that if statement.  The second time you call it, you might be getting a false returned, which is likely skipping over that if statement.

To debug this, I suggest several of these in different locations:

```
debug($this->request->data);
```

Also, debug printouts are cleared on redirect, so in the mean time, you may want to comment out the redirect inside the if statement like so:

```
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Успешно променихте профила си.', 'success_message');
    //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'profile'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($this->Auth->user() && $this->Auth->user('id') == $id) {
    $this->User->read(null, $id);
    $this->User->set(array(
        'email' => $this->data['User']['email'],
        'password' => $this->data['User']['password'],
        'social_profile' => 'bla bla'
    ));
    $this->User->save();
    // etc
```

may do what you're after.

more @ http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data